# ¿Cómo agregar script de bootstrap en html desde Linux?

Tags: bootstrap, linux

Al tratar de agregar los scripts de bootstrap en el html, en el head, no me funciona el bootstrap. Probé con el link CDN de bootstrap y funciona perfecto.

```
   <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="bootstrap/js/boostrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

La ruta de los archivos en Linux:
/home/rxvt/Área de trabalho/testes_html/bootstrap

Al colocar en el directorio /var/www/html, si me funciona el código.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la ruta donde esta el `index.html`?

Comment: si tu URL actual no es la raíz, debes tener una sub-carpeta bootstrap dentro de la carpeta donde te encuentras, o utilizar `/boostrap` al inicio de tu ruta.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando la virgulilla (~) que representa el directorio raiz de tu proyecto, en tu caso seria:

```
<script src="~/bootstrap/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/bootstrap/js/boostrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Espero que te sirva